# C# WinForms - run progressbar in new thread while waiting for process to stop in main thread

Tags: c#

I need a little help with my program. I am trying to show progressbar in marquee mode, when my main thread (Form) starts a new process and waits for process exit. This means I start pdflatex to compile TEX file and I show new form with progressbar until process WaitForExit() method is done. And I need to know if Im doing it in right way or there is another better method. I have a class called Progress which extends Form and is used for new thread.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Measuring
{
public class Progress : Form
{
    public Progress(Form form)
    {
        InitializeComponent(form);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent(Form parent)
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Font = parent.Font;
        this.Size = new Size(300, 40);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(parent.Left + ((parent.Width - this.Width) / 2), (parent.Top + ((parent.Height - this.Height) / 2)));

        ProgressBar progressbar = new ProgressBar();
        Label label = new Label();

        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Text = "Converting file to pdf";
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Top;          

        progressbar.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        progressbar.Maximum = 100;
        progressbar.Minimum = 0;

        progressbar.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        progressbar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressbar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 10;


        this.Controls.Add(label);
        this.Controls.Add(progressbar);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Now I have streamwrite method where at the end i call this:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = save.FileName;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Progress prg = new Progress(this);
        Thread t = new Thread(prg.Start);

        try
        {

            if (p.Start())
            {
                t.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                prg.Stop();
                if (p.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Conversion to pdf using LaTeX failed!" + Environment.NewLine + "No output file produced.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pdflatex is not installed!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

It seems to be OK but I dont know if it is really safe or not. I know that all exceptions are not handled but main things are Start() and Stop() methods.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: May be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) on the StackExchange. Assuming your code is in working order.

Comment: Why not simply start the process and wait for it to exit, all from the background thread?

Comment: This is one of those cases of "You're doing it wrong" ;) Good answer by Servy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a few problems here.  First off, you're creating multiple UI threads; you're trying to show another form in a different thread.  That's...almost always wrong.  It's very hard to work with, and the underlying framework often assumes there is only one UI thread, so it can cause bugs in otherwise functional operations.

Instead do your non-UI work outside of the UI thread, so the UI thread (the one and only UI thread) is free to continue processing UI events.

This is simple enough; in fact, we don't even need to create another thread at all.  The `Process` class already provides an event that will be fired when the process exits.  We can just add a handler to that event and then never wait on anything at all in the UI thread; we can let it continue on to processing UI events.

The only remaining issue is that the `Exited` event handler will be fired from a thread pool thread, not the UI thread, so we'll need to use `Invoke` to run some code in the UI thread.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = save.FileName;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += (sender, arguments) =>
{
    prg.Invoke(new Action(() => prg.Stop()));
    //TODO look at the process's status - display errors
};
prg.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply Sevy. The way I used was because I needed to show form and lock the main form so noone could modify or change anything in it.

But if I could have another question. Is there any way how to show progressbar maybe with label also because the form is closeable from windows panel. Maybe I can set that form cant be closed manually but it shows in win panel.

Comment: @user2962293 Which is what this does as well, but in a manor that is going to not have bugs, be easier to work with, and be easier to write/read/maintain.  Keep in mind your other form is using `ShowDialog`, so it's modal, which will disable the main form until it is closed.